# Cambiar la ruta al subir las fotos en mi web

Tags: html, laravel, base-de-datos

tengo un problema. Desde el panel de control de mi sitio, puedo subir un menu con fotos, lo sube bien pero las fotos no cargan. Las está guardando en otra carpeta del sitio y la ruta es otra.

Por ejemplo, cuando subo debería aparecer en assets/front/img/product/featured/1710252935.png pero me las guarda en core/assets/front/img/product/featured/1710252935.png

Entonces cuando aparece el menú, no aparece la foto porque la dirección donde no está la foto es la primera que les dejo assets/front/img/product/featured/1710252935.png

Aquí están los archivos del sitio: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSNAj.png

Y aquí donde dentro de Core donde esta public/asset/ que es donde guarda las fotos y que no aparecen en la pagina: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdRpN.png

Donde puede decirle que guarde las fotos en assets/front/img/product/featured/ y no en core/assets/front/img/product/featured/

Espero me puedan ayudar, saludos!

Comment: De que panel de control hablas? que tienen que ver todas las etiquetas con tu problema? cual es el codigo que provoca eso?